# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable when trying to subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples, subplot

Currently trying to make some subplots in python. This exact code worked yesterday, and now I am getting "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

The strange thing is it lets me run all these graphs separately in the command bar, but when I run the full code it only plots two of them before giving me this error. I have to restart the kernel to start plotting again or else anything I try to plot will give me that answer.

here is what I am trying to code:

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_ANK_ang[:,0], color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle = '--')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_ANK_ang[:,0]-angANKnvf_err, avg_ANK_ang[:,0]+angANKnvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#FF9848')
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_ANK_ang[:,1], color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_ANK_ang[:,1]-angANKcvf_err, avg_ANK_ang[:,1]+angANKcvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#089FFF')
plt.xticks([])
seaborn.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True)
plt.ylabel("Ankle")
plt.title("Angle (deg)")

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_MTP_ang[:,0], color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle = '--')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_MTP_ang[:,0]-angMTPnvf_err, avg_MTP_ang[:,0]+angMTPnvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#FF9848')
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_MTP_ang[:,1], color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_MTP_ang[:,1]-angMTPcvf_err, avg_MTP_ang[:,1]+angMTPcvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#089FFF')               
seaborn.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True) 
plt.plot = (x_axis, 0)             
plt.ylabel("MTP") 
plt.xlabel("% stance")

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_ANK_mom[:,0], color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle = '--')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_ANK_mom[:,0]-momANKnvf_err, avg_ANK_mom[:,0]+momANKnvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#FF9848')
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_ANK_mom[:,1], color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_ANK_mom[:,1]-momANKcvf_err, avg_ANK_mom[:,1]+momANKcvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#089FFF')             
plt.xticks([])
seaborn.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True)
plt.title("Moment (NM)")  

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_MTP_mom[:,0], color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle = '--')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_MTP_mom[:,0]-momMTPnvf_err, avg_MTP_mom[:,0]+momMTPnvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#FF9848')
plt.plot(x_axis, avg_MTP_mom[:,1], color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.fill_between(x_axis, avg_MTP_mom[:,1]-momMTPcvf_err, avg_MTP_mom[:,1]+momMTPcvf_err, alpha=0.5,  facecolor='#089FFF')             
seaborn.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True)
plt.xlabel("% stance")
```

the error:

```
  File "/Users/Laura/Box/NVF/Biomechanics data/Compile/compile.py", line 130, in <module>
    plt.plot(x_axis, avg_ANK_mom[:,0], color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle = '--')

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The other strange thing is it typically plots the first two plots before giving the error. (Unless I individually put them in the command window, then the first three will typically plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.plot = (x_axis, 0)
```

That line of code is the problem.  You've reassigned `plt.plot` to be a tuple variable, and it's not a function anymore.